# Fmtcount and Australian Babel

Tags: babel, fmtcount

How can I get `fmtcount` to work when babel is loaded with the Australian option?

Consider the following code which doesn't compile, due to babel australian not being supported:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}
    \numberstringnum{100}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but generally good practice: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Comment: Actually this is the first time I have used it, I copied and pasted from another question in order to produce a MWE for the purposes of this question. ;-)

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to create a file `fc-australian.def` by modifying the existent `fc-british.def`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you load `fmtcount` before `babel` (or don't load `babel` at all), `fmtcount` will fall back to english language strings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[australian]{babel}

\begin{document}

The current language: \languagename

\numberstringnum{100}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Here's my file list produced by adding `\listfiles` to the MWE (I'm using TeXLive 2012 with `babel` updated to v3.9c):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fmtcount.sty    2012/10/24 v2.02
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
fcprefix.sty    2012/09/28
fcnumparser.sty    2012/09/28
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
fc-english.def    2012/06/18
   babel.sty    2013/04/08 v3.9c The Babel package
 english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks, I actuall tried that before, it still throws error: `Missing number, treated as zero \adddialect\l@australian\l@british`

Comment: @ADP Does my MWE work for you? If yes, there must be something else going on, and you should update your question with a new example.

Comment: The document gets produced, however, the error gets thrown as per my previous comment. Copied and pasted from your MWE. Tried to build using lualatex and pdflatex.

Comment: @ADP Works for me with pdflatex. Did you delete all auxiliary files?

Comment: Yes, no change.

Comment: Your MWE works with my MiKTeX 2.9 (`babel` v3.8m for some reason) when using pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX. LuaLaTeX gives me: ! LuaTeX error ...6)/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:53: luatex-hyphen: no entry in language.dat.lua for this language: australian

Comment: TeX Live 2012’s LuaLaTeX gives me four errors "! LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: assertion failed!", while pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX work just like on MiKTeX. Looks like it’s something LuaLaTeX-specific, potentially a bug there?

Answer (score 6):

Create this file and name it `fc-australian.def`. Put it in the same directory as your test file for experimenting with it; if the tests are successful, move it in some place where TeX looks for input.

```
% File name: fc-australian.def
% This file has been obtained by modifying
% fc-british.def in the fmtcount bundle
\ProvidesFCLanguage{australian}[2013/06/20]
\FCloadlang{australian}
\let\@ordinalMaustralian\@ordinalMenglish
\let\@ordinalFaustralian\@ordinalMenglish
\let\@ordinalNaustralian\@ordinalMenglish
\let\@numberstringMaustralian\@numberstringMenglish
\let\@numberstringFaustralian\@numberstringMenglish
\let\@numberstringNaustralian\@numberstringMenglish
\let\@NumberstringMaustralian\@NumberstringMenglish
\let\@NumberstringFaustralian\@NumberstringMenglish
\let\@NumberstringNaustralian\@NumberstringMenglish
\let\@ordinalstringMaustralian\@ordinalstringMenglish
\let\@ordinalstringFaustralian\@ordinalstringMenglish
\let\@ordinalstringNaustralian\@ordinalstringMenglish
\let\@OrdinalstringMaustralian\@OrdinalstringMenglish
\let\@OrdinalstringFaustralian\@OrdinalstringMenglish
\let\@OrdinalstringNaustralian\@OrdinalstringMenglish
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `fc-australian.def'.
```

Now the example file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}
    \numberstringnum{100}

\end{document}
```

runs.

**Note** This will give errors with LuaLaTeX on TeX Live 2013, but it's not related to `fmtcount`. The problem is probably related to the recent changes in `babel` management. It should be reported to the people in charge. It disappears if I modify the entry in `language.dat.lua` for `ukenglish` with the addition of the synonym `australian`.

```
    ['ukenglish'] = {
            loader = 'loadhyph-en-gb.tex',
            lefthyphenmin = 2,
            righthyphenmin = 3,
            synonyms = { 'british', 'UKenglish', 'australian' },
            patterns = 'hyph-en-gb.pat.txt',
            hyphenation = 'hyph-en-gb.hyp.txt',
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Czech language. I had issue with using package bibleref with czech babel. fc-czech.def file helped.